# WinForm Calendar. Is there a freeware one?

Tags: .net, winforms

I'd like to display a month calendar with items on the calendar, much like Outlook's month view.

I see that there is a ASP.NET calendar but is there nothing for WinForms?

I don't want just a small drop down list date selection control. I'm looking for something like [this](http://screencast.com/t/Pyj51djsGNH)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a good one with source:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/docview/WinFormsCalendarView.aspx?msg=3153670#xx3153670xx

Comment: There's an updated fork of this project on sourceforge http://sourceforge.net/projects/winformscalenda/

Answer (score 1):

The standard `MonthCalendar` Control maybe? Although you can't add much info to a specific date. It is very much like the ASP.NET control.

Comment: See the link that I added to my posting (last sentence)

Comment: Are you sure? What properties are used to make the Winform Calendar that <A HREF="View?http://screencast.com/t/xDDvBvWlJ2v"> I see</A> look like an Outlook Month calendar that <A HEREF= "http://www.screencast.com/users/Dokmanc/folders/Jing/media/7217941d-af74-4431-b0d5-fcd3b8f7c56f">I want to see</A>

Comment: Let me try again:
I see:
http://screencast.com/t/xDDvBvWlJ2v

I want to see:

http://www.screencast.com/users/Dokmanc/folders/Jing/media/7217941d-af74-4431-b0d5-fcd3b8f7c56f

Comment: In the interest of not junking up this post too much until I get it right, see the link in my original msg

Answer (score -1):

DevExpress is offering over 60 controls free of charge – without royalties or distribution costs.

They have a controll named DateEdit Control that i think supports your needs.

DateEdit allows users to modify date values by selecting the desired date from the dropdown calendar or entering it manually. It offers the following features.

Customizable date editing formats via masks.
Keyboard and mouse wheel support for incrementing / decrementing the current date portion. Date portions (year, month, etc) can be selected using the navigation keys.
Optional Clear and Today buttons. 
Month and year scrolling using the buttons in the calendar header.
Optionally display individual week numbers. 
Current date indicator.
The ability to paint day cells manually.

[image]

http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WinForms/Editors/editors/DateEdit.xml

Comment: Note - This control may not be free - trial only?